# What is professional quality JavaScript refactoring plugin for Eclipse (or Intellij IDEA)?

Tags: javascript, eclipse, intellij-idea

Today when I tried to do simple renaming refactor in JavaScript using intellij IDEA 10, I was shocked what it did. It renamed that Class attribute everywhere regardless the attribute belonged to that class or not! For example `Baz.attr1` renamed to `Baz.attribute1`, it also renamed `Box.attr1` to `Box.attribute1`. Refactor Preview does not help here because there are hundreds of places in which the same attribute name is used under different situations like `this.attr1` type of references.

Eclipse does not even have JavaScript rename refactoring.

In additional to renaming I am looking to refactor a group of functions and move them to Object Literal notations such as

```
function foo() {

}
function bar() {
}
```

refactor to :

```
var MyCompany.Baz = {
 foo: function() {
  },
 bar: function() {
 }

}
```

It should refactor all references to those function calls in all the files including HTML and JSP files like `foo();` changing to `MyCompany.Baz.foo();`

There is no such thing in either IDE.

Is there high quality plugin available for JavaScript for Eclipse (prefer) or Intellij IDEA that would do the kinds refactorings of I am talking about?

Answer (score 8):

I believe that the kind of rename refactoring that you want is not possible in a dynamic language.

Let's say that you have your classes `Baz` and `Box` with the `attr1` attribute.

If we write something like:

```
var b;
if (someCondition) {
    b = createBox();
} else {
    b = createBaz();
}
b.attr1 = "value";
```

What should the refactoring program do?

Given that the type of the variable is only known when the corresponding code is executed, and that this type can differ at each invocation of that code, the computer is unable to determine to which definition an invocation of the attribute 'attr1' should be linked to.

Comment: That makes sense and in such cases I would expect a smart refactoring program to point me out to such lines instead of blindly changing b.attr1 = "value"; to b.attribute1 = "value";. But it should be automatic when its something like a = new Baz(); and b = new Box(); then it should not change b.attri to b.attribute1.

Comment: Have you invested in unit testing?  You are right through, preview/refactor should warn about shady cases, but if you need an automated tool to maintain code then you also need an automated tool to make sure it all works :)  That, and unit testing is generally awesome.